# Polynomial with two parameters input

Tags: polynomials

I have created a table which contains values (Z) from calculation which is effected by two variables Y and X. Here's snippet of the data (leftmost column = Y values, upmost row = X values):

```
    0   1           2           3           4           5           6           7           8           9           10
0,5 0   0,1925502   0,3960768   0,6112685   0,8387719   1,0791816   1,3330312   1,6007848   1,8828298   2,1794716   2,4909291
0,6 0   0,1698555   0,3495793   0,5398596   0,7413554   0,9546882   1,180433    1,41911     1,6711775   1,9370251   2,2169687
0,7 0   0,1520766   0,3131125   0,4837833   0,6647456   0,8566292   1,0600286   1,2754957   1,5035321   1,7445827   1,9990299
0,8 0   0,1377415   0,2836843   0,4384858   0,6027921   0,7772301   0,9624009   1,1588721   1,3671713   1,5877789   1,821123
0,9 0   0,1259214   0,2594031   0,4010818   0,5515882   0,7115404   0,8815377   1,0621535   1,2539294   1,4573681   1,6729284
1   0   0,1159985   0,2390085   0,3696449   0,5085209   0,6562422   0,813401    0,9805701   1,158297    1,3470974   1,5474503
1,1 0   0,1075444   0,2216253   0,3428358   0,4717707   0,609021    0,7551689   0,9107823   1,0764089   1,2525712   1,4397606
1,2 0   0,100252    0,2066254   0,3196922   0,4400282   0,5682092   0,7048051   0,8503761   1,0054668   1,1706014   1,3462784
1,3 0   0,0938949   0,1935456   0,2995035   0,412326    0,5325728   0,6608009   0,7975608   0,9433914   1,0988153   1,2643341
1,4 0   0,0883026   0,1820364   0,2817333   0,3879327   0,5011781   0,6220133   0,7509779   0,8886033   1,0354082   1,1918942
1,5 0   0,0833439   0,171829    0,2659684   0,3662845   0,473305    0,5875598   0,7095772   0,83988     0,9789815   1,1273809
1,6 0   0,0789162   0,1627128   0,2518855   0,3469399   0,4483885   0,5567476   0,6725337   0,7962603   0,9284338   1,0695499
1,7 0   0,074938    0,1545207   0,2392273   0,3295476   0,4259792   0,5290249   0,6391896   0,7569769   0,8828856   1,0174066
1,8 0   0,0713437   0,1471183   0,2277871   0,3138248   0,4057148   0,5039468   0,609014    0,72141     0,8416255   0,9701454
1,9 0   0,0680802   0,140396    0,2173961   0,2995408   0,3872999   0,4811503   0,5815735   0,6890531   0,8040716   0,9271072
2   0   0,0651034   0,1342638   0,2079159   0,2865061   0,3704913   0,460336    0,5565106   0,6594885   0,7697435   0,887747
```

I can calculate polynomial to return Z either from column or row vector but, can't figure out if it's possible to calculate polynomial which takes Y and X as input and returns Z value. Is this possible and, if it is, how this is done. Any thoughts?

Comment: It's certainly possible in theory - solve each column as $p_y(x)=\sum _{i=0}^n c_{i,y}x^i,$ and then find polynomials $p_i$ that match $p_i(y)=c_{i,y}.$ Then you get a matching polynomial  $$\sum_{i=0}^n p_i(y)x^i.$$

Comment: That will be painful and slow, but it will give a polynomial that exactly matches your data.

Answer (score 2):

If $y_0,\dots,y_m$ are your $y$ values, $x_0,\dots,x_m$ are your $x$ values, we will find a polynomial that is $0$ at every $(x_i,y_j)$ except at one particular value $(x_{i_0},y_{j_0}),$ where it will be $1.$

Let $f_{i_0}(x)=\prod_{i\neq i_0} (x-x_i).$ Then $f(x_i)=0$ except when $i=i_0,$ where $f(x_{i_0})\neq 0.$

Similarly, let $g_{i_0}(y)=\prod_{j\neq j_0}(y-y_j).$

Then $$h_{i_0,j_0}(x,y)=\frac{f_{i_0}(x)g_{j_0}(y)}{f_{i_0}(x_{i_0})g_{j_0}(y_{i_0})}$$

Has: $$h_{i_0,j_0}(x_i,y_j)=\begin{cases}1&i=i_0\text{ and } j=j_0\\0&\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Now if you want to match your polynomial $z_{ij}=p(x_i,y_j),$ you can choose:

$$p(x,y)=\sum_{i,j} z_{ij}h_{i,j}(x,y).$$

This is slightly nice, computationally, because you can precompute $\hat f_i(x)=f_i(x)/f_i(x_i)$ and $\hat g_j(y)=g_j(y)/g_j(y_j)$ and then combine them.

If $\hat f_i(x)=\sum_{i'=0}^n a_{i',i} x^{i'}$ and $\hat g_j(y)=\sum_{j'=0}^m b_{j',j} y^{j'}$ then:

$$p(x,y)=\sum_{(i',j')=(0,0)}^{(n,m)} \left(\sum_{i,j} z_{ij}a_{i',i}b_{j',j}\right)x^{i'}y^{j'}$$

It is still probably quite a messy answer.

Answer (score 0):

As my math skills are not very good, have to say, I did not fully understood Thomas Andrews's answer so I went the other path. I think my question is now solved to a level that I know one technique to take further.

What I did was:

1. calculated degree 3 polynomial for each row vector (Y's)

[image]

2. took coefficients of these polynomials and calculated new polynomials for each column vector (X's)

[image]

[image]

3. took these coefficients to [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/nromxdpxdj) for to test

[image]

As polynomial degrees are low the result is not exact.

Any thoughts?

Comment: "*the result is not exact*" $\;-\;$ Wasn't the question asking for an exact result? That's precisely what @ThomasAndrews' [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4677692/291201) provides.

Comment: @dxiv, I did not manage to implement Thomas's method so I don't know how slow it is nor how it interpolates between values in table. Also, my implementation is just sketching out the method so, result gets exact when I rise the degree of polynomials. I use LibreOffice Calc in Ubuntu and it freezes the PC quite often so kept the degree of polynomial and data size low.